# React.js keep scroll at bottom

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I have a `div` that grows in height as an animation. Instead of growing outside of the viewable area (and user having to scroll down), I'd like the window to automatically scroll with the `div` height. Locking the scroll position at the bottom of the page would work.

!!This is in React!!

I've tried millions of google/SO answers, none work/ arent specific enough.

code https://github.com/coryb08/corydbaker `npm install && npm start`

Comment: is it growing along with state changing?

Comment: Its just a css animation

Comment: should it scroll after animation is done or mid-animation?

Comment: mid-animation.  scroll show happen with the animation. Basically the scroll needs to be locked at the bottom of the page at all times. (obviously by default, scroll stays at top of page)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You provided very little information, but since we know it's in React, you could use JavaScript to make sure your div is scrolled all the way to the bottom at all all times.

```
class FullMenu extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = {
      class: "",
      div: ""
    }
    this.scrollToBottom = this.scrollToBottom.bind(this);
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    setInterval(this.scrollToBottom, 20);
  }
  scrollToBottom() {
    var scrollingElement = (document.scrollingElement || document.body); /* you could provide your scrolling element with react ref */
    scrollingElement.scrollTop = scrollingElement.scrollHeight;
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div id="FullMenu">
        {this.state.div}
        <div id="triangleDiv">
          <img
            className={this.state.class}
            onClick={() => {
              this.setState({ class: "bounce" })
              let that = this
              setTimeout(function() {
                that.setState({
                  class: "",
                  div: <div className="menuDiv" />
                })
              }, 1000)
            }}
            src={triangle}
            id="triangle"
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Note that above solution keeps the window scrolled at all times. If you wanted to scroll it only during animation, then you should use react's `CSSTransitionGroup` and use `clearInterval` to stop this behavior in `transitionEnd` lifecycle hook.

Comment: That isnt the problem. Creating the ref is the problem and incorporating it into your code isnt working

Comment: You should provide a minimal fiddle/snippet to show this problem, then incorporating any code into it would be easy.

Comment: React code snippets are impossible, so I uploaded it to github. https://github.com/coryb08/corydbaker `npm install && npm start` should do the trick. Its very basic right now, just two components

Comment: there's only README.md

Comment: Edit: i deleted the ref as it's not used. Also added a note below. No problem! :)

Answer (score 5):

You can use CSS alone
all you have to do is set the div styling

```
display: flex;
flex-direction: column-reverse
```

this should flip the div scroll and position it at the bottom

Comment: Thanks! This was exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: you are life saver, After a year, You still saved my life

Comment: Legend! I was using scrollTo which worked but wanted an instant bottom position and this is an absolute winner!